# Can't start WSL2 after updating to Windows 11

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, windows-11, windows-11-preview

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL2 before updating from Windows 10 to 11 beta, and in Windows 10 it always worked fine.

After the update I can still see the installed distribution like this:

```
PS C:\> wsl --list
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-20.04 (Default)
PS C:\>
```

But I can't start it anymore:

```
PS C:\> wsl
Access is denied.
PS C:\>
```

This happens even when I run PowerShell as Administrator, I get the same `Access is denied` as non-privileged and as Administrator user.

Does somebody have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: You should report this issue through the Feedback Hub.  The Linux kernel likely needs to be updated.

Comment: @Ramhound thx, done

Comment: However, this is a long standing issue, so I would attempt to shutdown the WSL instance and perform a system reboot.  [If that still does not work, run "WSL" within a Command Prompt with elevated permissions.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240409/access-is-denied-while-launching-ubuntu-wsl)

Comment: You might also remove / uninstall WSL , restart, and reinstall WSL . I had to do that.

Comment: @john did you have the same problem and then it worked after doing so? I prefer to not do that because then i'll have to setup everything inside my Ubuntu from scratch again, but if there's no other way then I can do it

Comment: I had an issue with WSL and that is how I solved it . I am not yet a big fan of WSL.

Comment: Under Windows 10, at least, an "Access Denied" when running `wsl.exe` is often caused by some form of encryption or compression.  Check that neither `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages{distribution_folder}` nor `%TEMP%` is encrypted or compressed.

Comment: Also, if you do have to uninstall/reinstall, make sure to copy out the `ext4.vhdx` file from your installation.  It can be restored afterwards to recover the filesystem.  Also check to see if a `wsl --export` will still work -- If so, use it to create a backup as well that can be `wsl --import`ed afterwards.

Comment: See if a WSL update is available. My Windows 1 Insider machine just updated WSL .

Comment: I'm really sorry, but in the end the issue was that BitDefender has blocked some executables that are used by the WSL2 (without showing me a notification). I'm guessing it did that because it didn't have the fingerprints of those new Windows 11 binaries in its list of trusted fingerprints yet. Thanks a lot for all the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem myself. The issue was that BitDefender has blocked some executables that are used by the WSL2 (without showing me a notification).
I'm guessing it did that because it didn't have the fingerprints of those new Windows 11 binaries in its list of trusted fingerprints yet.
Once BitDefender stopped blocking these binaries everything worked.

Comment: Could you detail, do you remember what those programs were?

Comment: I had the same issue, I uninstalled the MacAfee Anti-virous and problem solved.